# PHP query does not return result

Tags: php, mysql

This query is not returning any result as there seems to be an issue with the sql.

```
$sql = "select region_description from $DB_Table where region_id='".$region_id."' and region_status =(1)";
$res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 
$result = "( "; 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res); 
$result .= "\"" . $row["region_description"] . "\"";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
   echo "<br /> In!";
   $result .= " , \"" . $row["region_description"] . "\""; 
}
$result .= " )";
mysql_close($con);
if ($result) 
{
   return $result;
} 
else 
{
   return 0;
}
```

region_id is passed as 1.

I do have a record in the DB that fits the query criteria but no rows are returned when executed. I beleive the issue is in this part ,

```
region_id='".$region_id."'
```

so on using the gettype function in my php it turns out that the datatype of region_id is string not int and thus the failure of the query to function as my datatype in my tableis int. what would be the way to get parameter passed to be considered as an int in php. url below

```
GetRegions.php?region_id=1
```

Thanks

Comment: echo that query and paste into phpmyadmin query box and see the result

Comment: see updated answer of mine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

`$sql = "SELECT region_description FROM $DB_Table WHERE region_id = $region_id AND region_status = 1"`

The `region_id` column seems to be an integer type, don't compare it by using single quotes.

Comment: the query fails with error ' You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '. and region_status =1' at line 1

Comment: According to this validator: http://developer.mimer.se/validator/index.htm the query is OK. The only explanation why it would fail is that `$region_id` contains an invalid value (maybe not an integer ?). Before writing the query, check that value using the `is_int` function.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It says it is not an integer but i am passing it in the url as 1 or 2, which tells me that the value passed from the url is not treated as an integer. am passing these values as follows GetRegions.php?region_id=1

Comment: `$region_id = (int) (mysqli_real_escape_string ($dbconnection, $_GET['region_id'])); if (is_int ($region_id)) { //execute_query }` . What this does is first escape the value (in case there's something bad there) and then it attempts to cast it to an integer. If that fails, no query is executed.

Comment: thanks @SoboLAN but what i did was cast the parameter passed to int and execute the query. Works fine now. The issue was with the datatype passed in the url parameter.

Comment: what's the point in doing mysqli_real_escape_string? and what's the point in checking for is_int() **right after** you set the type to int explicitly?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel the escape is to protect against SQL Injection attacks. That variable/value goes into a SQL query, you SHOULD always escape it. And the call of `is_int ()` is to check if it's an int. The variable is explicitly cast to an int, but who guarantees you that the cast actually worked ? Maybe there are only letters there and it failed... Given the fact that it is checked to be an int, let's say that the escape was maybe not that necessary

Comment: `(int)` never fails. And escaping has nothing to do with injections. And it's exceptionally useless here.

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping the `;` at the end of your query.

Comment: post it in your first post, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

try this

`$sql = "select region_description from $DB_Table where region_id=$region_id AND region_status = 1";`

When you are comparing the field of type integer, you should not use single quote

### Good Luck

### Update 1

Use this.. It will work

`$sql = "select region_description from " .$DB_Table. " where region_id=" .$region_id. " AND region_status = 1";`

Comment: Thanks i did try that but i get the error ... You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '. and region_status =1' at line 1

Comment: what are datatype of your `region_id` & `region_status` field?? same can be seen by typing `DESCRIBE myTable`

Comment: else provide full table structure

Comment: data type for region_status is tinyint and region_id is int

Comment: see my updated answer... `$sql = "select region_description from " .$DB_Table. " where region_id=" .$region_id. " AND region_status = 1";`

Comment: still fails. The echo query with your sql shows as , select region_description from <tablename> where region_id= .1. and region_status =1. i dont think the dots are correct. running the same query i got in the echo without the dot does execute but no results when executing the php but i do get a result in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - your code is very messy. You mix variables inside string with escaping string, integers should be passed without `'`. Try with:

```
$sql = 'SELECT region_description FROM ' . $DB_Table . ' WHERE region_id = ' . $region_id . ' AND region_status = 1';
```

Also `;` should be removed.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need the single quotes around the region id i.e.

```
$sql = "SELECT region_description FROM $DB_Table WHERE region_id = $region_id AND region_status = 1"
```

Comment: I did try that but get the error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '. and region_status =1' at line 1

Comment: @AyubAhmed it cannot be. there is uppercase AND in the answer and lowercase one in the error message. You are running wrong code.

Comment: thanks @Col.Shrapnel. didnt get what you meant but do view my edit to my original post.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnet - I think this is a wind up. Funny I got a downvote for no reason (along with others)